# How to format current time in django views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am having difficulty formatting the current time in Django views and am seeking guidance on how to do so. Specifically, I am trying to display the date in the format 'year-month-date' or 'y,m,d'. Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this?

```
from django.utils import timezone
print('date :',timezone.now())
and it returns : 
date : 2020-12-31 18:34:29.309006+00:00
```

Desire output is : date : **2020-12-31**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you :)

Comment: glad to help, dont forget to give an uptick and accept the answer