# How do I convert 2021-01-05T23:19:30.685658Z to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: python, django

In my django app I am getting the date returned in the following format

```
2021-01-05T23:19:30.685658Z
```

How do I convert this to dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: Look up `strptime` in the Python documentation

Comment: and then `strftime`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format current time in django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524569/how-to-format-current-time-in-django-views)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.fromisoformat('2021-01-05T23:19:30.685658Z'[:-1])
dt = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(dt)
```

result will be `2021-01-05`